# How to publish a dist folder in npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a javascript library that I want to publish on npm: let's call it `foo`.
The problem is that the javascript files to be consumed by the clients are under a `dist` folder.
Therefore, for the moment the clients has to include `dist` in their `import` statement like this:

```
import { bar } from 'dist/foo'
```

I would like to allow clients to import the `foo` library without mentioning `dist` explicitly, like this:

```
import { bar } from 'foo'
```

Is there a way to add a property in `package.json` of `foo` or maybe in the `package.json` of the clients?

**Remark**: The reason why the javascript files are in a `dist` folder is because my library is written in `clojurescript`. Therefore the source files are under `src` and the generated files are under `dist`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a `main` section in your `package.json` :

> main: If you have a single module that serves as the entry point to your program (like what the "foo" package gives you at require("foo")), then you need to specify that in the "main" field.

ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers

But it will only work for a single file, if you need to `require` multiple files, you should only publish your `dist` folder :

```
npm publish dist
```

Comment: what should be the value of `main` in my case? `dist/foo`?

Comment: I see here https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/14970 that the feature I need is not yet implemented.
What is the difference between your suggestion and the suggested feature?

Comment: The difference is that `main` only works for a single file. If you want to `require` an other file you will have to include `dist` again.

Comment: I need to be able to include many files. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: You can publish only `dist` folder with `npm publish dist`

Comment: Is the advice for an older version of NPM? I don't see the the "dist" option documented here - https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-publish . And when I try to run it, I get an error message suggesting "dist" is being interpreted as a package name. " npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/dist - Not found"

Comment: Yeah this answer is incorrect #2023